# Why does mutate not accept a data.frame as a column to nest?

Tags: r, purrr, dplyr

```
library(tidyverse)
a = data.frame(c1 = c(1,2,3), c2 = c("a","b","c"))
b = data.frame(c3 = c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE))
a %>% mutate(c_nested = b)
```

produces an error:

> Error: Column `c_nested` is of unsupported class data.frame

How do I add a column that contains a nested data.frame?

Many thanks!

Comment: See https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3630

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can pass it as a `list` column

```
a %>% 
   mutate(c_nested = list(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
res <- 
  a %>% 
  `$<-`(c_nested, b)

str(res)

# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ c1      : num  1 2 3
#  $ c2      : Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3
#  $ c_nested:'data.frame': 3 obs. of  1 variable:
#   ..$ c3: logi  TRUE FALSE TRUE
```